# Changing array element has no effect

Tags: arrays, go

There is something wrong with the compiler or my understanding of Go. I have a weird bug and have whittled it down to a simple example. For some reason I can't change the array directly within a loop.

```
    var nums [2]int
    for i, v := range nums {
        if i == 0 {
            nums[i+1]++
        } else {
            fmt.Print(v)
        }
    }
```

This increments nums[1] then prints it.  So it should print 1 but it prints 0.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Using an array is probably wrong in Go.

Comment: @Volker You're mistaken - no such rule exists

Comment: That's why the rule is on your thumb! In all seriousness, Arrays are fine for static definitions (see go's time pkg for days of the week) - but for mutable values, slices are preferred. If you need a certain size, prealloc the slice with `make`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use an array in an expression you get its "value" (ie, a complete new copy of the array).  This includes using an array in the range expression of a loop.  So when you print `v` you are printing the copy, but the actual `nums` array *has* been changed.

Looping on a slice instead of the array gives you what you expect:

```
    var nums [2]int
    for i, v := range nums[:] {
        if i == 0 {
            nums[i+1]++
        } else {
            fmt.Print(v)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The range creates a copy of the array (and its values), so it can iterate over them.

If you plan on mutating an array (or a slice of that matter) during iteration, it's best to reference the array/slice directly - as the `v` value will be a copy and in your code an old copy of the array.

So try something like:

```
var nums [2]int
for i := range nums {
    if i == 0 {
        nums[i+1]++
    } else {
        fmt.Print(nums[i])
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iiJoF-V2pSj)